# Lots of error when running a method

Tags: java, android, exception

OK, So I have started programming in Eclipse, using Java, and making an Android App. In one of my activities, I am saving people's details - name and mobile number (to send SMS to them later). However when the method is executed a load of errors are thrown. The method looks like this, and is executed by clicking on a button (standard stuff):

It also fires another method, to write to a file:

```
public void addpeople_action_save(View view) {
    EditText et_addpeople_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addpeople_name);
    EditText et_addpeople_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addpeople_number);
    String person_name = et_addpeople_name.getText().toString();///parses from the EditText to a string.
    String person_number = et_addpeople_number.getText().toString();

    ///Next section is writing the two strings to a internal file, as a CSV format.
    ///eg: Bill, 0123567898
    ///this will actually append the string to an arraylist of strings, before writing it back to the file.
    ArrayList<PeopleDetails> peopledetails_return =Readpeopledetails();///creates an arraylist containing people's details
    ///read from file
    PeopleDetails person_details = new PeopleDetails("", ""); 
    person_details.name = person_name;
    person_details.number = person_number;
    peopledetails_return.add(person_details);
    peopledetails_return = sortList(peopledetails_return);
    peopledetails_write(peopledetails_return);

    /
    ///or will write a new file if it doesn't exist.
    ///New method(PeopleNumber, PeopleName, Filename)
    ///will write to file.
}
```

And the errors:

```
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     ... 11 more
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     at com.example.partyorganiser.AddPeople.addpeople_action_save(AddPeople.java:63)
01-02 08:47:20.290: E/AndroidRuntime(1966):     ... 14 more
```

Thanks for the help ;)

EDIT: Reader method code:

```
public ArrayList<PeopleDetails> Readpeopledetails(){        String filereadfrom = "";





            try{            InputStream filestream = openFileInput("PeopleDetailsFile");            if (filestream != null){///first time file is not created. Later will be created, when writing back to the file.
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(filestream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString);

            }
            filereadfrom = stringBuilder.toString();
            ///using two delimiters: ";" and ","
            ///split based on ";" to get people as a string, put in array
            ///then split all strings in that array, based on "," and place each into the array peopledetails
            String[] parsearray = filereadfrom.split(";");
            ArrayList<PeopleDetails> peopledetails_array = new ArrayList<PeopleDetails>();

                for(String personstring: parsearray){
                    String[] split = personstring.split(",");
                    PeopleDetails peopledetails_unit = new PeopleDetails("", "");
                    peopledetails_unit.name= split[0];
                    peopledetails_unit.number = split[1];
                    peopledetails_array.add(peopledetails_unit);

                      ///neatly initializes and writes to the peopledetails_array in one section. 
            }
                filestream.close();
                inputStreamReader.close();



            return peopledetails_array; }       }




                    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("File not found" , e.toString());
            }
                        catch(IOException e){
            Log.e("Can't read file" , e.toString());





                }       return null;
```

Comment: You should also post the errors you're getting.

Comment: Why don't you also share the exact error message and logs and point us to the lines causing the error? As of now, this question cannot be answered without further information.

Comment: You should provide the exact error you get

Comment: yeah, having problems editing it.

Comment: update it with the error logs. haven't the foggiest on which line it errors on...

Comment: NullPointerException in com.example.partyorganiser.AddPeople.addpeople_action_save(AddPeople.java:63) - what's on line 63?

Comment: Yeah, the app crashes when executing whatever is on AddPeople.java line 63, which tiggers a java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: ok, thanks for spotting that... quite new to java. :)

Comment: This is on line 63: "peopledetails_return.add(person_details);" - personally don't see a problem with that. the peopledetails_return is an arraylist of object, produced from reading a file. person_details in a single object... is there a problem if peopledetails_return is null??

Answer (score 1):

You have a NullPointerException in this location:

```
com.example.partyorganiser.AddPeople.addpeople_action_save(AddPeople.java:63)
```

hard to tell anything more

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that something is going wrong in the method call:

```
ArrayList<PeopleDetails> peopledetails_return =Readpeopledetails();
```

I suspect something is going wrong when you read the file and you are returning back a null from this method. Then later on you are trying to add an object to this collection, but as you returned Null you are getting a null pointer exception.

Please paste the code for that method in and we can confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here..

```
ArrayList<PeopleDetails> peopledetails_return =Readpeopledetails();
```

You can access this function when it return ***ArrayList***.

Comment: what should I replace that code with?? I come from a VB background, so assumed that the return of the Readpeopledetails() is passed onto the peopledetails_return

Comment: It's `ArrayList<PeopleDetails>` really but the code formatting in the question is broken and `<PeopleDetails>` gets consumed as a HTML tag..

Answer (score 1):

As the exceptions don't correspond directly to your code, it's hard to tell something else to what you've been already said.

However, the best way to debug those kind of exceptions is executing the application removing previously line by line of the snippet you think that might be failing (respectively blocks of codes), and see whether it still throws those exceptions or if something changes. Once you identify the point where it's throwing the exception, you can fence the reason of why it's happening.

Also using the Log utility to show the values of crucial variables helps so much. More info on this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html